# I have a project in TFS which is in Sync with server. and no files checkout. But still there is no lock symbol?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I wanted to have lock symbol for project that is not checked-out.

Comment: it doesn't have any symbol, just regular project icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VisualStudio 2010 :

From the file menu, click "Source Control" then "Change Source Control...". Select the project you want to be source-controlled and finally click on "Bind".

Source : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your Project might not be binded to the Source Control. If its binded, then you can see locked symbol, if the file is checked in, you will see person symbol, if its checked out to someone, you will see correct(right) symbol, if it checked out to you.  Click on the project and try refreshing it.